# Updating values in an array of objects with mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

This is a document from my annual budget collection

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8954cf3887ee089b4d7310"),
    "year" : 2018,
    "categories" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b8954cf3887ee089b4d7312"),
            "name" : "Logistics",
            "amount" : 1500
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b8954cf3887ee089b4d7311"),
            "name" : "Finance",
            "amount" : 23030
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

What I want to do append another object to the categories array. Below is my express patch request to do so:

```js
app.patch('/annualBudgets/:year' , (req, res) => {
            Budgets.update({year: parseInt(req.body.year)}, {'$set' : {
                'categories.$.name' : req.body.name,
                'categories.$.amount' : req.body.amount
            }}, function(err, docs) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err
                }
                res.send(docs).status(200);
            })
        })
```

I pass the following request to

```js
{
  "name" : "Help",
  "Amount": 122312
}
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong with the patch request. Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $push method since you are trying to update an array element

```
app.patch('/annualBudgets/:year' , (req, res) => {
            Budgets.update({year: parseInt(req.body.year)}, {'$push' : {categories : {
                name : req.body.name,
                amount : req.body.amount
           }}}, function(err, docs) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err
                }
                res.send(docs).status(200);
            })
        })
```